# Different Query result with and without using SQL Injection prevention syntax

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table `Books` with some columns named id, visibility, and config. Visibility is an integer column and config is json with content of the form

```
{"test": 
 {
  "test1": false, "ids": [1234, 567]}, 
  "visibility_options": {"all_people": true, "some_people": true}
}
```

I get correct and expected results when I run the query below:

```
select("DISTINCT(books.id), books.*")
.where([
  "
   books.visibility = 3
   AND
   JSON_EXTRACT(config, '$.visibility_options.all_people') = true
  "
])
```

I get an empty result when I run the query below to avoid SQL injection attacks.

```
select("DISTINCT(books.id), books.*")
.where([
  "
   books.visibility = ?
   AND
   JSON_EXTRACT(config, '$.visibility_options.all_people') = ?
  ",
    3,
    "true"
])
```

Is there something I am missing with the avoid SQL Injection query? I tried using "true" as 1, true, but still get the same empty result.

Comment: Not related to your question, but `DISTINCT` is not a function. Even if you put parentheses around `books.id`, the distinct applies to all the columns, not just the one you put parentheses around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the string value `'true'` as the parameter value, but MySQL's `true` keyword is not a string.

Here's a demonstration of the difference:

```
mysql> set @j = '{"test": ...}';

mysql> select JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.visibility_options.all_people');
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.visibility_options.all_people') |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| true                                                |
+-----------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.visibility_options.all_people') = 'true';
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.visibility_options.all_people') = 'true' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                            0 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.visibility_options.all_people') = true;
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.visibility_options.all_people') = true |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                          1 |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When you use JSON_EXTRACT(), the data type of the return value is JSON — not string or boolean. A JSON value `'true'` is not equal to a string value `'true'`

```
mysql> select cast('true' as json) = 'true';
+-------------------------------+
| cast('true' as json) = 'true' |
+-------------------------------+
|                             0 |
+-------------------------------+
```

But if you use JSON_UNQUOTE(), you can convert a JSON value `'true'` to the string equivalent.

```
mysql> select JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.visibility_options.all_people')) = 'true';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.visibility_options.all_people')) = 'true' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                          1 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This also works if you explicitly cast the value to a string.

```
mysql> select cast(cast('true' as json) as char) = 'true';
+---------------------------------------------+
| cast(cast('true' as json) as char) = 'true' |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                           1 |
+---------------------------------------------+

mysql> select CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.visibility_options.all_people') AS CHAR) = 'true';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.visibility_options.all_people') AS CHAR) = 'true' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                          1 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Honestly, using JSON in MySQL makes everything harder. I avoid it.